# Adding multiple post queries with parent and children to page - Best Way

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, get-children

So I am interested in allowing a custom menu to show "in three places: Menu area, Homepage body, and footer" based on the posttype "page" table list or parent and children entries and not using the WP nav menu system.

Reason is, I want users to control the menus displaying of my site using custom fields on each page. All 3 menus on the site will parent titles (w/ children page titles in the header menu only), but all with "different styling" done to each of the 3 sections.

I will make the function a shortcode 
`[mycustommenu area="header"]` which will allow me to pass "header" attribute into my function.

**So my questions are:**

**Should I use [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) OR the  [get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) / [get_children](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) function for this?**

**Should I run multiple loops separated by if statements `if(atts['header']):` or should I just do 1 loop and separate the object->results with the if statements?**

Just looking for the best solution in terms of optimization. And IF there is a better way to do this all together, please let me know :)

Comment: `WP_Query`is the better route 9/10 times, with the exception of a `wp_admin_json` response. I'd also recommend using the following to manage the query `function manage_query($wp_query){var_export($wp_query);exit;/*your code goes here*/}add_action('pre_get_posts','manage_query');`

Comment: Thanks for your response! So I'm trying to understand using pre_get_posts.... Am I trying to change an establish query somewhere? And when you say /*your code here*/ Are you saying to add the get_children function there. Please elaborate.

Comment: So to build a different query for each area? How would I style results? And how would I get children within each query? Please elaborate more.

Comment: My comment may not be relevant. Could you please provide read the following & update your question with example of the code? I'm finding it a little hard to figure out what you're asking: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get child-pages you'd query for post-type page where parent=ID_of_parent. This should help you understand wp-query vs get_posts a bit better: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts